# Xcode 10 pod errors

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift4

I updated my Xcode to version 10, I get the following error.

[image]

I updated cocoapods to 1.5.3 and Firebase (and all other pods) to the latest version. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Check if your pod framework is available in build settings

Comment: Update your pods, problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Because the pods are created and tested with specific version of Xcode, when a new version of Xcode is released the author of the pods should update the code, perform testing and release a new version. This takes time and probably in your case you need to wait a new version of the pods (last version sometimes doesn't mean compatible with last Xcode) or you can continue to use the previous version of Xcode.

If you want use the last version of Xcode you can check in the Cocoapods website if there is a new version of your pod. If the new version is available use the command (from the main folder of your project)

```
pod update [name of the pod]
```

And the pod will be updated. Then recompile your project.

Comment: Thank a lot @Lorenzo